# Group keys in collection of Dictionary and add values

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a collection of dictionaries like so (hope this makes sense, did on the fly)

```
dim dic as new ienumerable(of dictionary(of integer, double))= _
{dictionary(of integer, double) = new { {1, 0.5}, {5, 0.75} } _
,dictionary(of integer, double) = new { {1, 0.3}, {4, 0.46} }}
```

I want to get a `dictionary` (using linq) of the sum of the same keys like so

```
dictionary(of integer, double) = { {1, 0.8}, {4, 0.46}, {5, 0.75} }
```

So, in other words, I would like to `group` the `keys` and add the `values` of the grouped items.

I could easily do this with a `for loop` but I'm trying to learn linq and would like to figure it out using that instead. Could anyone give me some hints on how to get there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dictionary<int, int> dict1 = new Dictionary<int, int>() {{1,9},{2,10},{3,11} };
        Dictionary<int, int> dict1 = new Dictionary<int, int>() {{1,9},{2,10},{3,11} };
        Dictionary<int, int> dict2 = new Dictionary<int, int>() { { 1, 9 }, { 2, 10 }, { 3, 11 } };
        Dictionary<int, int> dict3 = new Dictionary<int, int>() { { 1, 9 }, { 2, 10 }, { 3, 11 } };
        List<Dictionary<int, int>> list = new List<Dictionary<int, int>> {dict1,dict2,dict3 };
        Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        list.SelectMany(a => a).GroupBy(a => a.Key).ToList().ForEach(el=>dictionary.Add(el.Key,el.Sum(sm=>sm.Value)));
```

I dont have Knowledge of VB.net but this is in C# . I hope this will help.